What is the default Java path Rstudio uses when starting a new session on Linux?
I have several Java versions installed on my Linux server, in
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131  (this is the correct version)
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171

I am using sparklyr package to connect to spark cluster, but when I start Rstudio and use sparklyr to get connect, it fails and tells me the Java version is not correct. The command Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME") returns just '' ; And after I use Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131'), everything works fine.
But the weird thing is I have already set JAVA_HOME = /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131 in my /etc/profile (else I will fail even I try to start spark in bash)
So here the question is, when we start Rstudio on Linux, where by default it will locate as its default Java execution location? And how could we change it (I don't want to change it every time I start a new R session).
FYI:

When I use alternatives --display java, it gives me the
jdk1.7.0_79 version, which is the wrong version and I think may be R session in Rstudio is also using this version. But it is a guess and not confirmed.
When I start R session directly in bash, Sys.getenv('JAVA_HOME') gives me the correct path. So only in
Rstudio, the setting is not correct/or is not set.


It's a system environment variable.
~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/jdk-21

If it's empty for some reason on RStudio (as it also was in my case), append a line with $JAVA_HOME, and restart RStudio.
~$ echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-21" >> ~/.Renviron

You can edit .Renviron also with a text editor such as vim.

I think this way may only works for the current user(the one "~" correspond to), how to make this take effect to all Rstudio user of this machine?

Can you try adding the line in sudo vim /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf (restart rstudio-server) or sudo vim /etc/environment (reboot system)?
